# python: datetime within module always provides date of first call

Tags: python, datetime

I load some module which has a `._today()` option, which works with `datetime`, and a class constructor. Every 30 seconds I re-create my class with `data = myModule.dataClass()`. The `__init__` of my class has as arguments `**init**(von=_today(),bis=_today(),somemore=something)'.

For the day I initialize the script, everything works; the next day, the data from the previous day is loaded. So the date is not updated.

Please help: What is that about?

I have a file called `myModule` that looks like this:

```
import datetime

def _today():
# returns todays date

    todays_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    return str(todays_date.day) + '.' + str(todays_date.month) + '.' + str(todays_date.year)


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__( self, von=_today(), bis=_today(), somemore=something ):

        self.somedata = []

        self.get_data( von, bis, somemore )
        self.read_data()
```

In addition I have a program that calls my data class and plots the data:

```
import aLot
import myModule

def some_plotting_routine(some_data):
    ...

def main():

    while True:

        most_recent_data = myModule.MyClass(somemore=something)
        some_plotting_routine(most_recent_data)

        matplotlib.pyplot.pause(30)
```

When I start the code, e.g. on Sep. 5th, 2013, everything works fine. The plot is updated every 30s. However, the next day, the code is updated every 30s, with data from the previous day, Sep. 5th.

If I interrupt the execution and type `myModule._today()` it returns the correct and current date, Sep. 6th. If I call `myModule.MyClass(somemore=something)` I get the old data, if I call `myModule.MyClass(von=myModule._today(),bis=myModule._today(),somemore=something)` I get the current data.

I tried various things, among others `del most_recent_data' before the next call. But it won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function default values are evaluated when the function is **defined**, not when it is called. Your default values are set in stone the moment Python loads the module.

Use sentinel values instead:

```
def __init__( self, von=None, bis=None, somemore=something ):
    if von is None:
        von = _today()
    if bis is None:
        bis = _today()
```

Now the values are set every time the function is called instead.

Note that your `_today()` function can be improved as well; create a `date` object, and use the `date.strftime()` function to format the date:

```
def _today():
    """Todays date formatted as a string"""

    todays_date = datetime.date.today()
    return todays_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

This will return dates as with *zeropadded* digits; you could also use:

```
    return '{0.day}.{0.month}.{0.year}'.format(todays_date)
```

to return non-zero-padded values. Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> adate = datetime.date(2013, 2, 14)
>>> adate.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
'14.02.2013'
>>> '{0.day}.{0.month}.{0.year}'.format(adate)
'14.2.2013'
```

Comment: Due to missing reputation I cannot upvote. But thanks for your fast reply. I guess that should work (I also cannot manipulate the date on my machine, so I have to wait until tomorrow to verify ::) ) And another thumps up for your advice with the string format time. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could define your function as:

```
import time
def _today():
    return time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

Then, pass as a default the above function, and call that inside your `__init__`. (A slightly different design pattern than using sentinels...)

```
def __init__(self, get_von=_today, get_bis=_today, somemore=something):
    self.von = get_von()
    self.bis = get_vis()
    # ...
```